# Bootstrap offset is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, offset

I'm just trying to experiment with Bootstrap and I cannot make the offset to work and I don't know why. Here's my code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2"> ABC </div>
    <div class="col-4"> DEF </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the `offset-2` doesn't move the column at all. Do you know why?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j7gmLs8z/ It is working. Have you imported Bootstrap correctly?

Comment: i will try that thank you very much Sujata

Comment: @SujataChanda - which version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work according to your requirements:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-stretch">

      <div class="col-4 col-md-offset-2">
        ABC
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        DEF
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Breaking it down, here’s how it works:

1.Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes.
2.In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
3.Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4.

Comment: 4.there are column prefixes to enhance columns in wide varients of devices available examples are:
.col-,.col-sm(540px),.col-md-(720px) etc...

Comment: Thanks that looks great, but it is best to "edit" the answer and put all the info in there. Cheers!